# .net EntityDataSource Error in QueryCreated Event

Tags: asp.net

I'm using an EntityDataSource Tag, on the QueryCreated i have the following:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="EntityDataSource1" ConnectionString="name=DB_ENTITY"
    DefaultContainerName="DB_ENTITY" EnableFlattening="False"  OnQueryCreated="EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated" EntitySetName="PhoneLogs">
```

In Code:

```
 Protected Sub EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated(sender As Object, e As QueryCreatedEventArgs)
        Dim query = TryCast(e.Query, IQueryable(Of PhoneLog))
        query = query.Where(Function(c) c.isExternal = True)
        e.Query = query
    End Sub
```

It's throwing an exception:

Overload resolution failed. I'm trying to always modify the query such that the entity will only return records where isExternal = True.

IsExternal is defined in a partial public class extending the EF class:

```
Partial Public Class PhoneLog
    Public ReadOnly Property isExternal As Boolean
        Get
            If Me.from_account_id = 0 Or Me.to_account_id = -1 Then Return True
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

What am i missing?